# Hash 'hashcat': Token length exception

Tags: cryptography, salt, password-hash, cryptographic-hash-function, hashcat

```
hashcat64.exe hashcat -m0 -a0 crackme.txt password.txt
```

> Device #1: Intel's OpenCL runtime(GPU only) is currently broken. We
> are waiting for updated OpenCL drivers from Intel
>
> Hash 'hashcat': Token length exception No hashes loaded.

I'm getting this message. I've attached a snapshot of my CL.
I've looked for any spaces in the hash directory and its format.
I've also tried changing all the Unicode formats of the .txt file.
Nothing seems to work. I've also updated the intel drivers.\

Can anyone help please. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: What command did you use? You didn't post it in your question.

Comment: oh im sorry please check i have edited it @Qiu

Comment: @Qiu crackme.txt has list of 19 digests that i got as an assignment to answers questions like.. type of hashing algorithm used and level of protection does the mechanism offer for passwords. So I can't change it. Though most of them has 33 chars which does seem like md5 could it be CRC-32??? I've just started learning all this

Comment: Using `-m 0` you declare that you want to crack hashes generated using MD5. Based on the error you get it seems like your hashes were generated using different algorithm.

Comment: @Qiu Acutally it needed to add rules. It's working fine now thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should look end of each line in your hash password containing files. If spaces are at there end of lines then you will get an error "token length exception" or "No hashes loaded". Just remove those spaces and then try.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking into this : I used two rules, you can use many of others to increase the efficiency.

```
hashcat64.exe hashcat -m0 -a0 crackme.txt password.txt -r rules/best64.rule
```

or

```
hashcat64.exe hashcat -m0 -a0 crackme.txt password.txt -r rules/d3ad0ne.rule
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if the hash file is not found. Note that the restore file effectively encodes the absolute path to the hash file, so this error can occur if it has moved when attempting to resume. (technically it saves the potentially relative path as specified when originally run, but it also saves the original working directory and cds there first)